# Sanitising a download URL with params being passed to send_file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sanitization

I have numerous files in a directory `app/assets/downloadables/` and I want authenticated users to be able to download arbitrary files by name in params within that directory or any subdirectories.

How can I sanitise the input to `send_file` to prevent users from accessing arbitrary files on the server?

At the moment I'm looking at doing something like this, but I'm not confident that it's safe:

```
DOWNLOADS_ROOT = File.join(Rails.root, "app", "assets", "downloadables")
# e.g. request.path = "/downloads/subdir/file1.pdf"
file = request.path.gsub(/^\/downloads\//,'').gsub('..','').split('/')
# send file /app/assets/downloadables/subdir/file1.pdf
send_file File.join(DOWNLOADS_ROOT, file)
```

Would this sufficiently protect against app-wide arbitrary file access or are there improvements or a different approach that would be better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer to this here: http://makandracards.com/makandra/1083-sanitize-user-generated-filenames-and-only-send-files-inside-a-given-directory

This file needed to be created per the link:

**app/controllers/shared/send_file_inside_trait.rb**

```
module ApplicationController::SendFileInsideTrait
  as_trait do

  private

    def send_file_inside(allowed_path, filename, options = {})
      path = File.expand_path(File.join(allowed_path, filename))
      if path.match Regexp.new('^' + Regexp.escape(allowed_path))
        send_file path, options
      else
        raise 'Disallowed file requested'
      end
    end

  end
end
```

To be used as follows in controllers:

```
send_file_inside File.join(Rails.root, 'app', 'assets', 'downloadables'), request.path.gsub(/^\/downloads\//,'').split('/')
```

The magic happens where the calculated path of allowed_path + file_name is entered into `expand_path` which will strip out any special directory browsing strings and just return an absolute path. That resolved path is then compared against the allowed_path to ensure that the file being requested resides within the allowed path and/or sub-directories.

Note that this solution requires the Modularity gem v2 https://github.com/makandra/modularity